# Should I use JMeter or Selenium for load and performance testing of Web applications?

Tags: performance, selenium, testing, jmeter

In your opinion which will be better the record or the creation of the scripts by Exemple with selenium and junit?
Does the record method allow test visibility and maintainability of the code?

Comment: I see this question pop up from time to time. Selenium is not the right tool for the job. JMeter was specifically designed for this. Use the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter(Open Source)/LoadRunner(Licensed) are the most popular tools for performance testing(Load testing).  Selenium is not the right choice for this job, it is the automation tool for web applications.

If you want to start in performance testing, I would suggest you to use JMeter for this job.

Comment: Can I Use Jmeter with Selenium :  for exemple  selenuim and junit as jar file  and import all into jmeter to tests performance of web Application??

Comment: You have to install plugins for both in JMeter. 
To use Selenium Webdriver with JMeter, you have to  install "Webdriver Set" plugins. The WebDriver sampler is useful for testing the performance of AJAX, GWT-based Web applications, and simulated user actions. For detail refer this https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler/
For junit, refer this https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-junit-jmeter/
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good way to use selenium for load testing, But Jmeter's main purpose is to do performance testing on web applications. So Jmeter is the right tool to to do performance related testing.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is a **browser** automation framework, it means 1 virtual user will kick off a real browser instance and modern web browsers are very CPU and memory intensive, for example [Firefox 72.0.2](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/72.0.2/system-requirements/) requires 1 CPU core and 2 GB or RAM per browser instance.

JMeter in its turn operates on [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) protocol level which has much less footprint.

So if you need to simulate large number of users - it's better to consider JMeter.

If you're doing client-side performance testing (measure JavaScript execution time, page rendering speed, etc.) - go for Selenium.

If you need both - create main load with JMeter and use 1-2 virtual users running Selenium

Check out [How to Convert Selenium Scripts into the JMX Converter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-convert-selenium-scripts-jmx-converter/) article to learn how Selenium tests can be transformed into JMeter using [Proxy2JMX](https://gettaurus.org/docs/Proxy2JMX/) service of the [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) tool